# Does a Single Electron moving in a vacuum tube with constant velocity radiate EM Wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

I assume that for any point the electron will pass, there will be a change in electric field because of the electron charge, and that change will generate magnetic field, and this will make an EM wave that will propagate.

I also think that in a DC current where multiple electrons are moving in the same direction, they will cancel effect of each other so there will be no EM Wave radiation.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Only accelerated charges radiate EM waves

Comment: A field that changes in time at a particular point is not necessarily a wave.  It can be a moving static field.

Comment: "moving static field" is it so because it is half wave i.e. from zero to -v then back to zero, as electron moves in one direction. as if there is a dc component of v/2 ?